# How in IRSSI can I switch channels? CTRL + number doesn't work

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, iterm

I just installed irssi using Brew in High Sierra. Using iTerm 2, I can't figure out how to change windows (channels). Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> for example doesn't take me to channel 2 like it would on an Linux machine.

Does anybody know the key combination that would make it work on iTerm and High Sierra?

Comment: Try `Esc` - you could have defined as the Meta key

Answer (score 11):

My Google skills were horrible so I posted the question. Found out it is ESC+number.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: Works for Mac Mojave

Comment: works for linux..

Comment: Works for me now

Answer (score 3):

You can also cycle through channels using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You could try using <kbd>ESC</kbd> + Number as the top answer says. If that doesn't work for you (it didn't for me), or if you prefer to use <kbd>Opt</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> as your Irssi Meta key (so you can select Irssi windows with <kbd>Opt</kbd> + Number), in iTerm2 go to:

**Preferences** > **Profiles** > **Keys** and set **Left Option key** to "Esc+".

Now you should be able to press <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to go to channel 2.